# Global sections of the dual of a globally generated rank two bundle on a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a rank two vector bundle on a K3 surface over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $E$ is globally generated and $\text{det}\,E$ is globally generated and big. Is it true that $H^2(E)=0$?

By Serre duality $H^2(E)=H^0(E^{\vee})^{\vee}=H^0(E\otimes (\text{det}\,E)^{\vee})^{\vee}$.

I am not able to conclude anything from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take for instance $E = \mathcal{O}_S \oplus \mathcal{O}_S(D)$, where $D$ is a very ample divisor.